# Querying user_meta table to look up email in the wp_users table

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress

I have created a simple html form to submit a value to a php script I have written.  I am using wordpress.  I want the script to look up a user in the user_meta table, and select the user ID.  I then want the script to look up the email of that user in the wp_users table.  Here is the code I have:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$userid = $wpdb->get_var  ( $wpdb->prepare (
"
SELECT user_id
FROM $wpdb->user_meta
WHERE user_meta = %s
",
 $_POST["submitted_value"] ) );

$useremail = $wpdb->get_var (
"
SELECT user_email
FROM $wpdb->wp_users
WHERE ID = %s
"
, $userid );

echo 'Car Owner Email is' . $useremail . '!';
echo "test" . $_POST["submitted_value"] ."!";

?>
```

Now, I have run the script and the last line appears to be working -- it is printing the 'submitted_value' from my html form - but it does not seem to be querying the database.

this is the entire php script -- I am placing it in the wordpress plugins directory -- do I need to add anything else to get it to query my wordpress database?

Answer (score 0):

You should update your code:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$userInfo = $wpdb->get_row  ( $wpdb->prepare ("
    SELECT user_id, user_email
    FROM $wpdb->usermeta um
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->users u ON (u.ID=um.user_id)
    WHERE meta_key = %s", //OR meta_value !!
    $_POST["submitted_value"]
));


echo 'Car Owner Email is' . $userInfo->user_email. '!';
echo "test" . $_POST["submitted_value"] ."!";

?>
```

But you can do it easily following the WP codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users/

```
$users = get_users(array('meta_key' => $_POST["submitted_value"]));
```

In this case you will get all possible users and you may need to run a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
    global $wpdb;
$query1 = "SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'your_meta_key_name' AND meta_value = '$_POST["submitted_value"]'";
$userid = $wpdb->get_var($query1);

$query = "SELECT user_email FROM wp_users WHERE ID = '$userid'";
$useremail = $wpdb->get_var($query);
```

1. Table name is **wp_usermeta and not wp_user_meta**
2. In WHERE Clause, you need to give a meta key with which the value has to be mapped. Ex: WHERE meta_key = 'nickname' and meta_value = 'pranita'.
   Replace 'your_meta_key_name' with proper key with which you are matching your form value.
3. If you don't understand fields, check wp_usermeta table in phpmyadmin.

Hope this helps. All The Best